# Migrating to Puppet 4.5.2

Tags: puppet, rhel6, puppet-agent

We are migrating to later versions of puppet.

New Version:

```
# puppet --version
4.5.2
```

Existing Version:

```
#puppet-3.8.7
```

Our existing site.pp is as follows:

```
#A default site.pp to do a quick test run
import "../classes/*"
import "../nodes/*"
   file { 'testfile':
       path => '/home/test/testfile',
       ensure => present,
       mode => 0755,
       content => "A test file to check a different manifestdir" ,
      }
 Exec { path => ["/bin" , "/sbini/", "/usr/bin" , "/usr/sbin/"]  }
```

Now since we are migrating to `Puppet 4`, i think below import function to  include multiple pp files will not work here in `Puppet 4`

```
import "../classes/*"
import "../nodes/*"
```

If I am not  wrong then I can copy all manifests under classes and nodes directory to the below manifest directory

```
/apps/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests/site.pp
```

Please suggest how to update the manifests to the later versions of Puppet or there is no compatibility issues ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I am not wrong then I can copy all manifests under classes and nodes directory to the below manifest directory

Yes, the manifest directory [will be imported recursively](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/dirs_manifest.html#directory-behavior-vs-single-file), so this is the best thing to do.

> Please suggest how to update the manifests to the later versions of Puppet or there is no compatibility issues ?

There are many subtle changes, so test your manifests on Puppet 3 with the future parser (`--parser future`) to see how well they work.

Start with [Puppet 3.x to 4.x: Get upgrade-ready](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/upgrade_major_pre.html), release notes and [Puppet 3.8 deprecations](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/3.8/reference/deprecated_summary.html).

Answer (score 0):

Following are the changes I had to perform to migrate code from Puppet to Puppet 4.

- **Use of import function is deprecated .**

**Puppet 3 Code:**

My site.pp was using import function to call other manifests as shown below

```
 import "../classes/*"
 import "../nodes/*"
```

**Puppet 4 Code:**

Copied nodes and classes directory to manifests directory as specified by `puppet config print manifest'

```
  # puppet config print manifest
   /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests

  # ls /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests
    classes nodes
```

No requirement for `site.pp` in my case as we are having manifests for multiple nodes. Putting classes and nodes to manifests directory will lead puppet to read each of the node manifests node recursively

- **Syntax change in writing Puppet templates**

  **Puppet 3 Code :**

  `<%= ipaddress %>   dev.example.com`

  Was seeing the following error when applying on Puppet 4

  `Call, Failed to parse template /etc/puppet/templates/Node-002/hosts.erb:
  Filepath: /etc/puppet/templates/Node-002/hosts.erb:
  Line: 1
  Detail: undefined local variable or method 'ipaddress' for #<Puppet::Parser::TemplateWrapper:0x007ffa98fb55c8>`

  **Puppet 4 Code:**

Updated the code as follows and after that the manifests was getting  applied fine
      `<%= @ipaddress %>  node-002.example.com`

**- Representation of numeric attribute value**

**Puppet 3 Code:**

```
 ` file { "/etc/sudoers":
     path => "/etc/sudoers",
     ...
     mode => 440,
    }    `
```

This was failing with the below error

```
     `Error: Failed to apply catalog: Parameter mode failed on File[/etc/sudoers]: The file mode specification must be a string, not 'Fixnum' at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests/classes/user_default.pp:7`
```

**Puppet 4 Code:** Fix was to put mode value within quotes

```
   `file { "/etc/sudoers":
     path => "/etc/sudoers",
     ...
     mode => "440",
    }      `
```

These are the major issues I faced while migrating to Puppet 4 . After that the migration was smooth.